# Скрин и вывод полезных данных

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать скрипт который будет выводить со сторонних сайтов только то, что мне нужно. Но почему то он не находит. Собственно исходный код:

```
<?
$addr = "http://site.host/index.php";  // адрес страницы
$begblock1 = "<label for="; // идентификатор начала блока

$begin = "<label for="; // фрагмент HTML-кода до полезных данных
$end = "</div></div></div><br>"; // фрагмент HTML-кода после полезных данных

$result = array();  // массив строк результата

$screen = file($addr);

$i = 0;
while ($i < sizeof($screen) && strpos($screen[$i], $begblock1) == false) {$i++;}
$temp = explode($begin, $screen[$i + 2]);
$temp = explode($end, $temp[1]);
$eok = $temp[0];

echo "<p><B>$eok</B></p>";
?>
```

Где я ошибся и в чём??

Comment: Я бы сказал, что подход в корне не верный. Тут бы регулярные выражения использовать. Ну а в данном коде есть просто логические ошибки:
откуда известно что в $screen[$i + 2] есть что-то? А вдруг в исходном коде добавится количество строк после искомого блока?

Comment: Либо можете воспользоватся библиотеками для парсинга html, например phpQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какое-то жуткое извращение, а не код.
Делайте примерно так:

```
$text= file_get_contents($addr);
$pos1= strpos($text, $begblock1);
if ($pos1>-1){
    $pos1=strpos($text, $begin, $pos1);
    $pos2= strpos($text, $end, $pos1);
    $result= substring($text, $pos1, $pos2);
} else {
    // если ничего не найдено
}
```

Или регулярным выражением, если больше нравится.

```
$text= file_get_contents($addr);
$re= "#".$begin."(.*?)".$end."#s"; // это прокатит для бегин и энд из текста вопроса, для других не гарантируется
preg_match_all($re, $text, $arr);
$result= $arr[0][1];
```

Comment: Если хоть на секунду задуматься, а не тупо копипастить код, то станет понятно, что это опечатка и речь о substr().

Comment: Да, извините. Функции в разных языках похожи друг на друга, перепутать легко, а этот код писал без проверки запуском. Надо так:  

    substr($text, $pos1, $pos2-$pos1)

Comment: И не должно "ничё" выводить, где вывод-то $result?

Comment: ooops :-[ Спасибо за ответ! Тема закрыта. ReinRaus +